# Root password not working when trying to update

Tags: password, root, upgrade, sles

Running SLES12 on a VirtualBox VM I get the notification that there are software updates. Trying to invoke the update, a popup appears and forces input of administrator password.

[image: Password interface]

When I enter the password for the `root` user, I get the error message

> Sorry, that didn't work. Please try again.

But I am sure that I entered the correct password. I also tried the password for the current user (who is member of the `sudo` group), but that also fails.

Logging in as `root` and going `su` on the shell both work fine with the password, but this dialog fails. Who can tell my why and how to solve this problem?

## Update

Both passwords, the `root` password and the current user's password work fine all the time. Only this dialog returns that error.

Comment: Have you tried current user's password?

Comment: Yes, "I also tried the password for the current user"

Comment: Can you show `# faillog -u $(whoami)`?

Comment: Does the command-line `sudo` work for this user? The authentication dialog box probably uses the same mechanism as sudo.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, both passwords, the `root` password and the current user's password work fine all the time. Only this dialog returns that error.

Comment: @black `faillog` is not installed on that SLES machine. And `/var/log/faillog` is empty.